# Multithreading and mutexes

Tags: c, multithreading, allegro5

I'm currently beginning development on an indie game in C using the Allegro cross-platform library. I figured that I would separate things like input, sound, game engine, and graphics into their own separate threads to increase the program's robustness. Having no experience in multithreading whatsoever, my question is:

If I have a section of data in memory (say, a pointer to a data structure), is it okay for one thread to write to it at will and another to read from it at will, or would each thread have to use a mutex to lock the memory, then read or write, then unlock?

In particular, I was thinking about the interaction between the game engine and the video renderer. (This is in 2D.) My plan was for the engine to process user input, then spit out the appropriate audio and video to be fed to the speakers and monitor. I was thinking that I'd have a global pointer to the next bitmap to be drawn on the screen, and the code for the game engine and the renderer would be something like this:

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *nextBitmap;
boolean using;

void GameEngine ()
  {

  ALLEGRO_BITMAP *oldBitmap;

  while (ContinueGameEngine())
    {
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *bitmap = al_create_bitmap (width, height);
    MakeTheBitmap (bitmap);
    while (using) ; //The other thread is using the bitmap. Don't mess with it!
    al_destroy_bitmap (nextBitmap);
    nextBitmap = bitmap;
    }

  }

void Renderer ()
  {

  while (ContinueRenderer())
    {
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *bitmap = al_clone_bitmap (nextBitmap);
    DrawBitmapOnScreen (bitmap);
    }

  }
```

This seems unstable... maybe something would happen in the call to `al_clone_bitmap` but I am not quite certain how to handle something like this. I would use a mutex on the bitmap, but mutexes seem like they take time to lock and unlock and I'd like both of these threads (especially the game engine thread) to run as fast as possible. I also read up on something called a condition, but I have absolutely no idea how a condition would be applicable or useful, although I'm sure they are. Could someone point me to a tutorial on mutexes and conditions (preferably POSIX, not Windows), so I can try to figure all this out?

Comment: Some Allegro notes: Allegro already is running those various components on different threads as needed by the particular platform. Also note that all of the drawing operations for a given display need to happen from the same thread that created the display. If you load a bitmap from a secondary thread, you can call `al_clone_bitmap()` on the display thread... but you shouldn't do that on every frame. IMO, you shouldn't be fishing for reasons to use more threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have a section of data in memory (say, a pointer to a data
>   structure), is it okay for one thread to write to it at will and
>   another to read from it at will

The answer is "it depends" which usually means "no".

Depending on what you're writing/reading, and depending on the logic of your program, you could wind up with wild results or corruption if you try writing and reading with no synchronization and you're not absolutely sure that writes and reads are atomic.

So you should just use a mutex unless:

1. You're absolutely sure that writes and reads are atomic, and you're absolutely sure that one thread is only reading (ideally you'd use some kind of specific support for atomic operations such as the `Interlocked` family of functions from WinAPI).
2. You absolutely need the tiny performance gain from not locking.

Also worth noting that your `while (using);` construct would be a lot more reliable, correct, and would probably even perform better if you used a [spin lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_lock) (again if you're absolutely sure you need a spin lock, rather than a mutex).

Answer (score 1):

The tool that you need is called *atomic operations* which would ensure that the reader thread only reads whole data as written by the other thread. If you don't use such operations, the data may only be read partially, thus what it read may may make no sense at all in terms of your application.

The new standard C11 has these operations, but it is not yet widely implemented. But many compilers should have extension that implement these. E.g gcc has a series of builtin functions that start with a `__sync` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of man pages in 'google'. Search for them. I found http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html in a few search minutes:

Besides, begin with a so little example, increasing difficulty. Firstable with threads creation and termination, threads returns, threads sincronization. Continue with posix mutex and conditions and understand all these terms.

One important documentation feed is linux man and info pages.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a section of data in memory (say, a pointer to a data structure), is it okay for one thread to write to it at will and another to read from it at will, or would each thread have to use a mutex to lock the memory, then read or write, then unlock?

If you have section of data in memory where two different threads are reading and writing this is called the critical section and is a common issue of the consumer and producer.

There are many resources that speak to this issue:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/sync-31/index.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/producer-consumer

But yes if you are going to be using two different threads to read and write you will have to implement the use of mutexes or another form of locking and unlocking.